# Passing Parameters to a SQLSRV WHERE IN query

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm new to parametrized queries. I have following query.

```
SELECT  * FROM CrmCustomer WHERE crmcustomer_expense >? AND crmcustomer_expense <? AND crmcustomer_map_prop2 IN (SELECT sub_email  FROM abc WHERE sub_id = ?  OR sub_id = ? OR sub_id = ?)
```

When I hard code the parameter array as bellow, It works. But when I make the array programatically it gives different result. Both queries run successfully and give result. But correct result set is returned with when hard coded.

Hard coded parameter array

```
$filter_params2 = array(1000, 7000, '1501184385','807654340','100006497021111');
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you give some sample datas with table here?

Comment: @SanalK I have added the table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution. In my parameter array which is created programtically, all the parameters are strings. I have to force them to be int like bellow for integer parametrss. I think otherwise sqlsrv drivers assigns wrong parameters for place holders.

```
$filter_params2 = intval($ds_filter);
```